# Ubuntu 16.04 | Teamviewer not installed but working

Tags: 16.04, bug-reporting, debugging, teamviewer

First sorry for my mispell i'm French, here's my problem, i'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and a version of Teamviewer (15.0.14842) is installed on my computer. I didn't install it and after a few searches with help of a french forum, we can't find any file remaining or something making us able to remove it.
You can find below the commands we try :
https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22411589#p22411589

Let me know if you want to know something else and thanks by advane for your help!

Comment: Have you tried left Windows key and enter `Startup` to see the startup applications when your PC boots? If listed, you can remove the app from there.

Comment: Try `apt list --installed teamviewer*` and if it returns results uninstall them with `sudo apt remove RESULT` change `RESULT` with the returned results from the command above after inspecting and making sure they belong to TeamViewer. That is how you remove apt installed software on Ubuntu **not** by using `rm` command

Comment: Hi guys, nothing in Startup for me, and nothing in apt list too, we've already tried it that's why we go by rm after that